# How to deal with rounding errors in python math.ceil

Tags: python, math

The following code snippet is giving 6 as a result:

```
import math
number = (1 - 0.99) * 500
math.ceil(number)
```

while the (mathematically) correct answer would be 5. Presumably this is a rounding problem - what is the best way to enforce the correct solution?

Comment: Are you able to use the `decimal.Decimal` class? The short/general answer to your question is that you cannot 'enforce the correct solution' using floating point numbers.

Comment: To give you constructive answers, we should know what bothers you in this result. More precisely, for what application case does this make a difference ? As you know, 0.9900000 should yield 5, but the very close 0.9899999 should yield 6, so you are on a borderline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Presumably this is a rounding problem

Yes:

```
>>> 1 - 0.99
0.010000000000000009
>>> (1 - 0.99) * 500
5.000000000000004
```

> what is the best way to enforce the correct solution?

You could use a [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) instead of a `float`:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> import math
>>> (1 - Decimal("0.99")) * 500
Decimal('5.00')
>>> math.ceil((1 - Decimal("0.99")) * 500)
5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a floating-point error since some numbers can't be represented exactly (infinitely many numbers have to be represented using a finite number of bits -- there has to be some trade-offs). This is why you lose some precision with floating point operations:

```
>>> 1-0.99
0.010000000000000009
```

Try Decimal:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as d
>>> result = (1 - d("0.99")) * 500
>>> result
Decimal('5.00')
>>> math.ceil(result)
5.0
```

**Edit**

It may look like all the numbers have exact representations:

```
>>> a = 1.0; b = 0.99; c = 0.01
>>> a, b, c
(1.0, 0.99, 0.01)
```

So this result might seem surprising:

```
>>> a - b
0.010000000000000009
>>> a - b == c
False
```

But it's just the precision and rounding errors that accumulate. Here are the same numbers and calculation, but showing more digits:

```
>>> def o(f): return "%.30f" % f
>>> o(a)
'1.000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> o(b)
'0.989999999999999991118215802999'
>>> o(c)
'0.010000000000000000208166817117'
>>> o(a-b)
'0.010000000000000008881784197001'
```

Comment: Misleading example, the cast to `int` will always truncate and would make this appear to work even for plain `float`s.

Comment: Oops, copied the wrong line from my interactive session. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 rounds to 17 significant digits. It is a **different model** from real math.

Comment: *"Python 2.7 rounds to 17 significant digits"* - that's not quite true, either, that's just how it's *displayed*. The short version is that it's impossible to represent all of the infinitely many real numbers in a finite number of binary bits, this is a problem common to all floating point implementations and not just to Python.

Answer (score 0):

The given answers are correct, this is a case of rounding error. However, I think it would be useful to include why this happens.

In hardware, floating point numbers are base 2 (AKA binary). The problem is that most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as [binary fractions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Data_Representation_and_Practical_Exercise/Fundamentals_of_Data_Representation/Binary_fractions). The translation of that is (in general) floating point numbers are only approximated by the binary floating point numbers actually stored in the machine.